# How do you write a server control in order for it to support partial postbacks in ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've got the following issue: I've got a WebForms Page which contains a column layout which is flickering when reloading custom server controls within the placeholder ph1.

To avoid this i was thinking about improving our servercontrols to support partial postbacks. I don't quite know how to accomplish this. So when a control triggers a postback i only want udp2 to update its contents instead of udp1 reacting to the raised postback.

My page structure is like this:

```
<updatepanel id="udp1">
 <tree>
 </tree>
 <updatepanel id="udp2">
  <ContentTemplate>
   <div id="ph1" runat="server"></div> <!--- receives generated servercontrol's
  </ContentTemplate>
 </updatepanel>
</updatepanel>
```

So far my attempts of making this work did not work out and udp1 always reacted as well and reloaded its entire content.

Can someone give me any useful tips on how to do this correctly?

Creation of the servercontrols happens like this :

// following function called in OnLoad/IndexChanged on ComboBox/TabChanged on Tabs of the page

```
public void CreateControls()
{
 var dataItems = GetData();
 foreach(var data in dataItems)
 {
  var control = CreateServerControl(data); // typeof CustomServerControl
  control.ID = "generated"+data.Identifier.ToString();
  ph1.Controls.Add(control);
 }
}
```

Is there an interface of some sort i have to implement on CustomServerControl to cause this control to be updated when raising a postback within the next available UpdatePanel (but only udp2, not upd1)

Code used within CustomServerControl to initiate postback on Client:

```
var options = new PostBackOptions(this, "update"); 
// turns into javascript:__doPostBack('somerenderedid','update');
link.href = string.Format("javascript:{0};", this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(options));
```

**EDIT 1**:

As Alexander pointed out i had a look at [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1117028.aspx), which is exactely my problem. I went ahead, created a sample project with this ServerControl: And placed it in a Page

```
[ParseChildren(false)]
public class TestControl : WebControl
{
    protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey
    {
        get { return HtmlTextWriterTag.A; }
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        var pbo = new PostBackOptions(this, "update");
        this.Attributes.Add("href", string.Format("javascript:{0};", this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(pbo)));

        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="a" Namespace="NestedUpdatePanelTest"             Assembly="NestedUpdatePanelTest" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="frmMain" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="TheScriptManager" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="aupParent" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <a:TestControl runat="server">outer</a:TestControl>
        <asp:Button ID="btnParent" runat="server" Text="Update the parent (and all childs of course)" />
        <%= "Parent panel last updated at:" + DateTime.Now.ToString( ) %>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="aupChild" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <a:TestControl runat="server">inner</a:TestControl>
                <asp:Button ID="btnChild" runat="server" Text="Update only the child" />
                <%= "Child panel last updated at:" + DateTime.Now.ToString( ) %>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Pressing the asp:Button elements does exactely what i want. Clicking the links however does not. What's the necessary changes to the TestControl to make it work like the buttons?

Comment: How are you adding the UpdatePanel to your Server Control? Show us your code, please.

Comment: It's the other way around. i'm adding controls to the server div within the ContentTemplate of an UpdatePanel

Comment: I do not see you creating a proper UpdatePanel. Since you're able to use `ph1` directly I suspect your panel doesn't work at all.

Comment: If they are working properly, did you post mock code? This link will help you with nested UpdatePanels: http://forums.asp.net/t/1117028.aspx

Comment: @Alexander it's partially mock code. in reality it's <asp:UpdatePanel>. I will go through your link and try it out in a test project. Thanks for now. I'll be back soon. I'm not sure tho why the panel should not work at all? I've used it in similar ways before and as long as i'm using telerik controls it's working. So i'm guessing there's something to do to make it work with a partial postback. Anyway - Checking out your link now.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks Alexander for your input, even if noone replies with other improvements to what i've come up with now, i've got a working solution thanks to you now.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

However i'm not sure wether that's the intended way to go about making a servercontrol update the closest UpdatePanel? Corrections and feedback are welcome. Otherwise i'll mark this as answer.

(I wish past me knew about this sooner)

```
[ParseChildren(false)]
public class TestControl : WebControl, IPostBackEventHandler
{
    protected override HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey
    {
        get { return HtmlTextWriterTag.A; }
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        var pbo = new PostBackOptions(this, "update");
        this.Attributes.Add("href", string.Format("javascript:{0};", this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(pbo)));
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(this);

        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }

    // works when used in UpdatePanel.Triggers property.
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;

    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        var h = SomeEvent;
        if(h != null)
           h(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        UpdatePanel p;
        Control parent = this.Parent;
        while (parent != null)
        {
            p = parent as UpdatePanel;
            if (p != null)
            {
                p.Update();
                return;
            }

            parent = parent.Parent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try having your control simply raise an event, and let the UpdatePanel react to that via Trigger declaration.

Comment: are you talking about something like public event EventHandler AsyncPostBack; (following within RaisePostBackEvent) if(AsyncPostBack != null) AsyncPostBack (this, EventArgs.Empty);
in combination with using the Triggers Property of an UpdatePanel? Does that work without any additional code? That would explain the existance of the bool AutoPostBack on telerik controls to me.

Comment: Would be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks again, declarative doesn't work for generated elements does not work, but i've tested it in the test project and your suggestion in general does work. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction!